# Antlr4 instruction keywords and longest-statement matching

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

I am attempting to write a grammar, but I've found a problem occurring that I'm not quite sure how to solve 'elegantly'.

The issue is that I have 'bro' as a reserved instruction keyword, and it can be followed(or not) by a predication statement. IE: 'bro_t' or 'bro'.

Now, the issue is that currently 'bro_t' matches the definition for ID, while 'bro' is a token by itself, and clearly 'bro_t' is longer than 'bro', so the parser matches that statement to an ID and the parse fails. The solutions that I have come up with are to make 'bro_t' and 'bro_f' reserved as well, but that would be relatively time consuming for the entire instruction set. The other solution that I was looking at was wildcard operators, but I don't really understand if they are applicable here and if so how to apply them.

Grammar:

```
predicate
        : '_t' '<' register '>' | '_f' '<' register '>' | ;

operation
    : 'bro' predicate ;

ID: ('a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '_') ( 'a' .. 'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0' .. '9' | '_' | '$' | '.')* ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not do:

```
operation
 : BRO '<' register '>'
 ;

BRO : 'bro' ( '_' [a-z]+ )?
ID  : [a-zA-Z_] [a-zA-Z0-9_$.]*;
```

?